# Using CloudID, Username and Password to connect to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have been using NEST to connect to my development Elasticsearch (v6). Now I have deployed my application to [cloud.elastic.co](https://cloud.elastic.co).

I have got this info form my deployment:

- Username: elastic
- Password: somepassword
- CloudID:  mydomain:somemorechars

I used to connect to my dev environment like this:

```
Node = new Uri("http://localhost:9200");
ConnectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(Node)
    .DefaultIndex("my-index-name")
    .DefaultMappingFor<MyDocumentObject>(m => m.IndexName("my-index-name"));
```

I am not sure, how should I change my `ConnectionSettings` to connect to this cloud server?

I have seen [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/current/configuration-options.html), but not really sure what to do.

Comment: You can get your elasticsearch cluster url from your deployment page in Elastic Cloud. You can use that url as uri and pass credentials in your connection settings. Usually, the cloud ID provided can be used in beats config like filebeat, metricbeat etc. but in your case you need to use your elasticsearch cluster url.

Comment: We have plans to support the CloudID in the client in the future, but for now, you can simply use the Elasticsearch URL in the constructor to `ConnectionSettings`

Comment: Pass Username and Password in `.BasicAuthentication(...)` on `ConnectionSettings`

Comment: @ben5556: thanks a lot, so I found my elasticUrl, the port number is: 9243 (not 9200), is normal?

Comment: @RussCam, thanks a lot. So something like this: ConnectionSettings("username:password:https://url:port/")? If I use this, then  would the credentials be passed only on the first call when client is establishing the connection? Or on every request?

Comment: @Hooman yes port number 9243 is correct!

Comment: @HoomanBahreini credentials are passed on every request